# Is it possible to have multiple parameter alternatives?

Tags: swift, xcode, parameters

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
func myFunc(myObject: MyObjectA){}
```

But what if I want `myObject` to be `MyObjectB` or `MyObjectC` instead? Is there a way to have multiple possible parameter alternatives for one and the same parameter?

Note: I don't want an additional parameter, I want the same parameter to be able to take many different classes. Something like this:

```
func myFunc(myObject: MyObjectA || MyObjectB){}
```

If you want a more detailed approach with my real code: I have a combat `function` where currently the character is able to attack the enemy. I would like to be able to use the same function for when the enemy attacks the character.

```
func combat(character: Character, enemy: Enemy, completion: @escaping() -> Void) {

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101))
    print(String(character.characterAttack - enemy.enemyDefence), "% chance to hit.")

    if(randomNumber <= (character.characterAttack - enemy.enemyDefence)) {
        enemy.enemyHealth = (enemy.enemyHealth - character.characterDamage)
        print("HIT", randomNumber, "% ", String(enemy.enemyHealth))

    }else{
        print("MISS", randomNumber)
    }
    if(enemy.enemyHealth > 0) {
        print("Enemy has ", String(enemy.enemyHealth), " health left")
    }else{
        print("Enemy Destroyed")
        completion()
    }
}
```

So instead of `character: Character, enemy: Enemy` as parameters I would like it to be `attacker: CharacterOrEnemy, defender: EnemyOrCharacter` and change the rest of the function accordingly.

Comment: @matt There is a bit more explanation in the question now with my real code. Tell me more about overload!

Comment: Yes this sounds like a generic protocol with an associated type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't have the behaviour you are seeking in the fashion you want.

What you can do is one of the following solutions:

1. Create multiple functions with different function signature
2. Make `MyObjectA`, `MyObjectB` etc. either conform to the same protocol or subclass the same class
3. Generics

**Approach 1 (Multiple function) details**

```
func myFunc(myObject: MyObjectA){
}

func myFunc(myObject: MyObjectB){
}
```

**Approach 2 (Protocol) details:**

```
protocol SomethingProtocol {
}

class MyObjectA: SomethingProtocol {
}

class MyObjectB: SomethingProtocol {
}

func myFunc(myObject: SomethingProtocol){ 
}
```

**Approach 2 (SubClassing) details:**

```
class SomeClass {
}

class MyObjectA: SomeClass {
}

class MyObjectB: SomeClass {
}

func myFunc(myObject: SomeClass){ 
}
```

**Approach 3 (Generics) details:**

```
func myFunc<T>(myObject: T){
}
```

The correct solution will be dependent upon your exact use case.

Edit: Based upon your exact use case, according to me, the correct solution should be that you create a protocol `Attackable` and make `Character` and `Enemy` conform to it.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I also think the protocol solution will work best. I have very little experience using it though. Do you think you could give a quick example based on my code above? Very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use generics. Your function would look like this:

```
func myFunc<T>(myObject: T){}
```

here's the official guide on generics

[Swift Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Any`.

```
func myFunc(myObject: Any){
   if let objA = myObject as? ObjectA {
       // TODO when myObject is a member of class ObjectA
   }
   // same for objB,C...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your situation reminds me of this example from my book, using generic protocols:

```
protocol Wieldable {
}
struct Sword : Wieldable {
}
struct Bow : Wieldable {
}
protocol Fighter {
    associatedtype Enemy : Fighter
    associatedtype Weapon : Wieldable
    func steal(weapon:Self.Enemy.Weapon, from:Self.Enemy)
}
struct Soldier : Fighter {
    typealias Weapon = Sword
    typealias Enemy = Archer
    func steal(weapon:Bow, from:Archer) {
    }
}
struct Archer : Fighter {
    typealias Weapon = Bow
    typealias Enemy = Soldier
    func steal (weapon:Sword, from:Soldier) {
    }
}

struct Camp<T:Fighter> {
    var spy : T.Enemy?
}
```

In that example archers and soldiers are enemies. The spy in an archer camp can only be a soldier and vice versa. A soldier can only steal a bow from an archer and vice versa (that is, an archer an only steal a sword from a soldier). This seems very parallel to your idea of a character paired with an enemy.

Answer (score 0):

You could also pass Any as type and test in the function.
Here is a toy example.

```
func myFunc(myObject: Any) {
    if let object = myObject as? Int {
        print(object, "This is an Int")
    } else if let object = myObject as? Double {
        print(object, "This is a Double")
    } else {
        print(myObject, "This is not an Int nor Double")
    }
}

let x = myFunc(myObject: 5)
let y = myFunc(myObject: 5.0)
let z = myFunc(myObject: "Hello")
```

Yields

```
5 This is an Int
5.0 This is a Double
Hello This is not an Int nor Double
```